# Make filtering by "tags" in careers easy by making the filter itself clickable

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I am not talking about the normal/coding tags, but rather these:

[image]

*Not sure what the are called; someone that knows better, please edit the question title.*

This would make quick filtering easier rather than the current implementation where you have to hunt for the filters.

Comment: Our designers call these "badges". Good suggestion, we'll look into it and provide an update shortly. In the meantime, note that you can search for jobs with the "work remotely" badge via this route: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/remote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion! We've implemented this feature, so you can now click on any of the badges and the search results will be updated accordingly.